# Symbol to the right of equation

Tags: equations, align

I want the contradiction symbol to the right of the equation without moving the equations to the left.

I've written

```
\begin{align*}  
u(2-t, 1, 3-t)              & > (2,1,3)     \\
1                           & > 1  
\qquad \qquad \text{\lightning}
\end{align*}
```

but that moves the whole equation to the left.

Comment: `\makebox[0pt][l]{\qquad\qquad\lightning}` But, please, add a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Will do next time egreg.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I've come to the decision of never advertising `\rlap` in answers, unless in definition code. People start using it and can found themselves scratching their head when `\rlap` comes between paragraphs.

Comment: @egreg: OK, I will remove my comment shortly.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way for adding some text whilst not reserving space for it is to use

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{...}
```

which makes a box of zero width, with the text starting from the left margin of the box, so it will stick to the right but, as far as TeX is concerned, it takes no space.

So your code should be

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{lipsum}% to add context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align*}
u(2-t, 1, 3-t) & < (2,1,3)     \\
1              & < 1\makebox[0pt][l]{\qquad\qquad\Lightning}
\end{align*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The `lipsum` package is used just to provide text around the display, to show the centering.

Of course you should check visually that the symbol doesn't go past the margin: there's no way to do this automatically (or it would be *very* complicated).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The symbol's command is `\Lightning`, not `\lightning`. 
   Here I show a way:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
u(2-t, 1, 3-t) & < (2,1,3)     \\
1              & < 1 & &\text{\qquad \Lightning}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]